# Issue with fly out menu using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a menu that flies out, however it will not return to its original state.

```
let toggleNavStatus = function () {
  let toggleNavStatus = true;
  let getsidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  if (toggleNavStatus === true) {
    getsidebar.style.left = "0px";
  } else if (toggleNavStatus === false) {
    getsidebar.style.left = "-250px";
  }
}
```

Comment: When will `toggleNavStatus` be false? You don't do anything to change it in the code you've shown.

Comment: let toggleNavStatus = true; Every single time you call the function, you are setting that variable to true, and as result, you will never get to the else if.

Comment: It was originally true but when I've been messing about with it I must of changed it. When the toggleNavStatus = true nothing works, but when it = false it will come out.

Comment: let navSlide = function () {
  let getsidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
 if(getsidebar.style.left){
           getsidebar.style.left = '-250px';
       } else {
            getsidebar.style.left = `0px`;
       }

      }

This works but will only work once.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let toggleStatus = false;
let toggleNav = function () {
let getsidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
if (toggleStatus === true) {
  getsidebar.style.left = "0px";
} else {
  getsidebar.style.left = "-250px";
}
toggleStatus = !toggleStatus;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, the variable and the function had the same name, fixed now.